# wordpress 4.8 high cpu usage

Tags: wordpress, cpu-usage, wordpress-4.8

recently I updated wordprees to latest version 4.8. but I found there is a high cpu usage in backend that the page load, drafting and publishing took a lot of time. but the frontend is ok. I searched and asked some people. they have this issue too. anyone have this problem or can solve that? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced such problem recently after updating wordpress. I have used this worpress plugin: ShortPixel Image Optimizer

if it does not work then you can also try EWWW Image Optimizer